# redundant import statement appears from nowhere in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

It's not the first time I've noticed that while editing python files in vscode `import` statement appears from nowhere, without my permission, like code below:

```
from unittest import result
```

What is it? How to prevent such insertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of auto import completion of Pylance. To disable this go to VSCode's Extensions tab, open Pylance settings [and disable this setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64350455/14795260).