# How to turn off VS Code's Python auto-fix feature in Pylance?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I need to make some targeted edits in a Python source tree. VSCode's Pylance extension is "helping" me by removing unused imports in a file, every time I save the file.

How can I turn this feature off, aside from disabling the Pylance extension entirely?

Comment: This is probably something that you can change in the settings. Without knowing your setup, it is hard to say what exactly is causing this, but I would suggest looking for the `Editor: Format On Save` and `Editor: Default Formatter` settings, or perhaps the Python linter

Comment: I have tried looking in the settings for any `On Save` and `Lint`  and a bunch of settings. But nothing works: the damn thing keeps on removing lines in the file that I do not want to be changed with this set of commits.

Comment: It might be Pylance... ok yes it was Pylance: I disabled the Pylance extension and now it does not do this. But I liked Pylance, I just want it to not remove imports so eagerly.

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3436

Comment: Please don't close, the cited "duplicate" is a different feature https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658375/vscode-python-extension-how-can-i-disable-autocompletion-from-inserting-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following configuration in **settings.json** to turn off automatic deletion of unused imports

```json
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": false,
    },
```

There are two **settings.json** files. The **Workspace settings.json** file will overwrite the same configurations in **User settings.json**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This setting was set to `true` for some mysterious reason in Workspace settings.json and I had no idea that this file even existed.